# Rewriting URL's to obscure directory name in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, geoip

This question may be too general for SO. Here goes anyway:

I'm looking to use [GEOIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/) to detect user location. If the user's IP is then from India, I would redirect them from https://www.example.com to https://www.example.com/in/

The issue I have is that I need the URL to be https://www.example.com + "/in/" + rest of original requested URL (if applicable), only IF the user's IP is in India.

I would then like to show in the browser only the original requested URL, https://www.example.com, so the user is not aware they have been directed to /in/

I'm using Maxmind's .htaccess GEOIP redirection currently, but am looking to potentially use the following service http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/ to achieve.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^IN$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/in/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /in/$1 [L]
```